# Wrapping in aluminun foil and place it in a skillet pan

Tags: vegetables, pan, skillet, aluminum-foil, foil-cooking

If I wrap something in aluminum foil and place it inside a non-stick skillet pan while cooking something is that something that could e.g. ruin the pan or ruin the food?
Specifically I had in mind wrapping vegetables

Comment: what do you hope to accomplish with this method? Off the top of my head you may scorch the pan, ruining it.

Comment: Why not just cover the pan?

Comment: Consider parchment paper?

Comment: @SteveChambers: I was thinking it might speed up the cooking of the veggies

Comment: @user3528438: Won't that catch fire? Or melt with the food?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it can ruin the pan. Non-stick pans are very sensitive to overheating. When their bottom is well covered with fat or fluid and pieces of food, the heat coming from the stove gets conducted from the pan to the food, and it usually doesn't overheat. But if you place a bundle on the pan, there will be large spots not in direct contact with cooling fluid (food) and so the teflon will get destroyed by the heat.

Wrapped cooking techniques are not usually meant for pans. They are much more typical in ovens (or in fire/embers, in more traditional settings). Sometimes wrapping is also done in steaming. But doing it in a pan is highly unusual. So consider looking up typical recipes and following them.

If you really need to do wrapping on a stovetop, use a pan material which can take the extreme heat, this would be cast iron (seasoned, not enameled) or uncoated stainless steel.

Comment: I had seen someone put the vegies capped with something like an iron cap inside a grill and thought of the aluminum foil

Comment: Putting wrapped vegetables on the grill is different from putting them wrapped on the pan, it is more comparable to the embers thing.